# Use different PHP version in VSCode workspace PHPStan

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, version, workspace, phpstan

I would like to use a different PHP version than my default in my current VScode workspace for PHPstan.

PHPstan keeps using my default PHP version from my windows commandline.

The error I get is;

```
PHP Fatal error:  Composer detected issues in your platform: Your Composer dependencies require a PHP version ">= 8.1.0". You are running 8.0.19.
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the key `phpstan.phpPath` in your workspace settings.json

Your workspace settings.json is found in the .vscode folder of your project.

The settings.json will be as follows;

```
{
    "phpstan.phpPath": "C:/PHP/php-8.1.6/php.exe",
}
```